# How to "uniq" an array, keeping the last duplicate of each element instead of the first?

Tags: ruby

When `Array#uniq` is called, the new array keeps the *first* occurrence of each duplicate:

```
["a", "b", "c", "a"].uniq #=> ["a", "b", "c"]
```

Does the standard library provide a clean way to "uniq" an array, but keep the *last* occurrence of duplicate elements?

e.g.:

```
["b", "c", "a"]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can accomplish this by reversing the array, uniquing it, and then reversing it again to the original order:

```
["a", "b", "c", "a"].reverse.uniq.reverse
#=> ["b", "c", "a"]
```

Comment: what if, it is a huge array and the repetitive elements distributed randomly? :)

Comment: @marmeladze are you suggesting a failing case? If so post it and I can redefine my answer.

Comment: Excellent! After some brief testing with [Benchmark](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html), this does **not** increase time taken in any meaningful way, as I had feared.

Comment: @GavinMiller don't take serious - the question doesn't make sense. 
if repetitive elements are distributed randomly there is no meaning to choose this but not that :) 
it's a bit like - http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/197821/is-the-uncertainty-principle-a-logical-consequence-from-the-wave-particle-dualit

Comment: You could reduce memory requirements by changing `reverse.uniq.reverse` to `reverse.uniq.reverse!`. If you could mutate the array, you could bang the first `reverse` as well. `uniq` cannot be banged as well (without a bit of fudging--see the benchmark in my answer) since `uniq!` returns `nil` if no change is made.

Comment: @marmeladze, I don't follow your logic. Suppose we are presented with the array `[1,2,1]` and are asked to uniquify it as the OP has specified (i.e., to return `[2,1]` rather than `[1,2]`). Does it matter how the array was produced?

Comment: grandpa, of course it doesn't matter. or may be matters. i don't know. 
i've also noted below - it's just a joke. beacuse it doesn't make sense. but if you want to be faced with absolute absurdity here you are :)

let's say we have an array A. A.length = n where n->Inf. there are hundred thousands of repetitive a_1, a_2, a_3 ... and we don't know the exact indexes of these elements as a whole. Is there a predefined procedure to choose unique elements in this order? [a_2, a_1, a_4, a_3 ... a_2k-1]  {n%2==1 ?  2k-1=n : 2k = n}.

 ... one must imagine sisyphus happy :)

Answer (score 2):

This is another way:

```
require 'set'

def reverse_uniq(arr)
  s = Set.new
  arr.reverse_each.with_object([]) { |e,a| a.unshift(e) if s.add?(e) }
end
```

For example:

```
reverse_uniq [1,2,3,4,3,2,1]
  #=> [4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Let's compare methods for speed, for a large array:

```
require 'fruity'
require 'set'

arr = Array.new(1e6) { rand(1e5) }

compare do 
  re     { s = Set.new; arr.reverse_each.with_object([]) { |e,a|
             a.unshift(e) if s.add?(e) } }
  rur    { arr.reverse.uniq.reverse }
  rurb   { arr.reverse.uniq.reverse! }
  rubrb  { (arr.unshift(arr.first)).reverse.uniq!.reverse! }
  rbubrb { (arr << arr[-1]).reverse!.uniq!.reverse! }
end

Running each test once. Test will take about 27 seconds.
rur is similar to rurb
rurb is similar to rubrb
rubrb is similar to rbubrb
rbubrb is faster than re by 30.000000000000004% ± 10.0%
```

The first bits in `rubrb` and `rbubrb` are to ensure: 1) `uniq!` does not return `nil` when `arr==arr.uniq`; and 2) the elements of the array returned are ordered as they are in the array returned by `rur`.

So, if memory is limited, you might want to use `rbubrb` if you can mutate the array or `rubrb` if you can't, else just use `rur`.

Comment: It looks like `unshift` mutates arr. Would the better way to do that be `arr.reverse.unshift(arr.first).uniq!.reverse!`. The first reverse should copy it, preventing the unshift from mutating the original and prevent `uniq!` from returning nil. Though... honestly... maybe just using multiple statements is better that way you just don't rely on the return value of `uniq!`

Comment: @Darinth, I agree, but as I look at what I wrote eight years ago I'm a bit ashamed of having included rubrb and rbubrb, which are truly awful.

Comment: I mean... you could update it. This is still one of the top google searches when I was looking for how to take the last value in a uniq. And sometimes you do want to save on that memory usage. I actually just had to implement something similar in real world code and getting a benefit, not so much in speed as in reducing the memory footprint as it's a memory constrained AWS instance, was something I wanted. Using multiple lines and reverse, uniq!, reverse! was essentially what I did.